# Php resource id was changed after storing in session

Tags: php, session

I am doing practicing how to store value into session in PHP.

The problem is that:

when I call `echo $_SESSION['handle']`  in my testsession.php ,it shows 0.

when I use `var_dump($_SESSION['handle'])` ,it shows that int(0).

storeValueParctice.php

```
$handle = fopen ( "test.txt", "r" );
$_SESSION['handle']=$handle;
echo $_SESSION['handle'] // it will show resource id#(somenumber)
```

testsession.php

```
echo $_SESSION['handle']; //it shows 0.
var_dump($_SESSION['handle']);//it shows that int(0).
fseek ( $_SESSION['handle'], 0 ); // this will give me an error which is 
//Warning: fseek() expects parameter 1 to be resource, integer given .
```

I am not sure why does this happen.

How do I get resource ID # in `testsession.php`?

I want to pass `$_SESSION['handle']` from `storeValueParctice.php` to `testsession.php` and do some file operations in `testsession.php`.

Comment: I'm not sure this will work for you.  The scope of the file handle is the current process and ends when the script ends.  I dont believe its possible to pass an open file handle to another process in this method.

Comment: You can't save the file resource reference in a session and then re-use it in another instance. If you want to operate on a file in the session, save the name of the file (so `$_SESSION['file_name']` instead of `$_SESSION['handle']`) and re-open that file when you need it again.

Answer (score 0):

first add the php session start command on the top of the page:

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
```

fopen() function returns File object.

if you want to get the file content into session try this:

```
$handle = file_get_contents ( "test.txt" );
$_SESSION['handle']=$handle;
var_dump($_SESSION['handle']); // it will show resource id#(somenumber)
```

this should solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `session_start()` at the top of both the pages to be able to pass the values on.

**storeValueParctice.php**:

```
 <?php 

     session_start(); <===

     ...rest of the code...
 ?>
```

**testsession.php**

```
<?php 

     session_start(); <===

    ...rest of the code...
 ?>
```

Refer: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_sessions.htm